# Cosa significa "spasimante" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Da piccola Artemisia era anche crudele e ora fa l’atto di gettare la cavalletta sull’amica: il suo viso s’increspa fingendo 
>   uno sforzo e una soddisfazione così truculenta, che solo per quella si giustifica l’urlo *spasimante* di Cecilia.

Ho cercato il significato di "spasimante" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire cosa significa in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Spasimante” è il participio presente di [“spasimare”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spasimare/); da solo, “spasimante” è usato più spesso nel senso di “corteggiatore” e simili, ma qui evidentemente l'uso è letterale.

Comment: Capisco, grazie! Il mio problema era che avevo cercato "spasimante", ma non "spasimare".